# Add class to every last element on the row AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to add a class to the every last element in that row. Here I have a ng-repeat and showing it in three columns in a row so every 3rd(last) column should have a class. Though I am in the beginning stage of Angular I couldn't figure it out.

Thanks for your kind answers.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use $last (a exposed property of ng-repeat) and ng-class

```
<div class="container" ng-repeat="item in items">
     <div ng-class="{'yourClass':$last}"> your content...</div>

</div>
```

I would have tried to provide a better example, but its hard to guess the structure of what you are working on based on your input.

Comment: say I have an array of 9 elem's [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9] and I am going to display this in a row which has three columns like the first col will have 123 and the sec will have 456 and so on.. I want to insert a class to the last element in that col here it should be 3,6&9. $last will always carry take the 9th elem i.e the last in that array

Comment: Are there always going to be 3 columns and 9 elements, or are we talking about variable number of columns and elements and, in that case, are the elements always going to be grouped in sets of 3?